# How to display rows where date is less than x time

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `forserverid`='518' AND `date` ?????
```

The date columns contains a unix timestamp, how do I make it so it only shows rows where the unix timestamp in the date column is less than X time (3 hours in my case). i want to do this filter within the mysql query if possible.

Thanks :)

Comment: `\`date\` > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR`

Comment: @Nemoden That didn't work, I'm not using a "date" column, It's just a regular column with a unix timestamp in it.

Comment: Three hours compared against which time? (date column > ? + 3hs)

Comment: @Juan I have a unix timestamp stored in the date column, I want it to only shows rows that are not older than three hours.

Comment: @MassacreGamingnet is it an `int` / `INTEGER` column or a text column? If it's a text column then you'll have poor query performance because converting text to `int` is a non-SARGable operation.

Comment: @Dai it's a int column :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix time stamp is in secods so 3 hs are 3 * 60 * 60 seconds.

The condition should be `date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 3 * 60 * 60`

Comment: Worked, thank you! You're awesome! ;)